# Azure Function not binding to appsettings when deployed

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function app written in C# with Visual Studio using version 3.0.9 of Functions SDK. In the same directory as the csproj file and the host.json, I have an appsettings.json file with the following content:

```json
{
    "test-queue": "test,
    "myOptions": {
      "batchSize": 5000
    }
}
```

The function works fine when I run it locally but for some reason it doesn't seem to bind to the appsettings file when it is deployed to Azure. I use the following startup class:

```cs
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var builtConfig = builder.ConfigurationBuilder.Build();
        var keyVaultName = builtConfig["AzureKeyVaultName"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultName))
        {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/");
        }

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
    }

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();
       
        builder.Services.AddOptions<MyOptions>()
            .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.GetSection("myOptions").Bind(settings);
            });
    }   
}
```

I have a function class like this:

```cs
public class MyFunction
{
    private readonly MyOptions options;

    public MyFunction(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
    {
        this.options = options.Value;
    }

    [FunctionName("Test")]
    public async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("%test-queue%")] MyParameters parameters,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Batch size: {options.BatchSize}");
    }
}
```

The trouble is, the function doesn't seem to be using the appsettings file. I get an InvalidOperationException on startup saying '%test-queue%' does not resolve to a value." I can get rid of the queue binding and hard code the queue name. That makes the funtion run Okay but then the log file says the batch size is 0 instead of 5000.

Again, it works when running locally but not when it is deployed. The `optional` flag is false when registering the appsettings file in the startup so it must be getting found.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a partial solution by replacing

```cs
builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

with

```cs
FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

        builder.ConfigurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

It is still making me hard code the queue names but batchSize variable is getting set at least.